# Storing unicode characters with Realm

Tags: android, android-studio, unicode, realm

I want to read a JSON string from a text file and store it's objects to a Realm file.

Text file created with Delphi and encoded in UTF-8. I'm reading String from text-file with a Scanner class and then extract from it some JSONObjects and JSONArrays. there is no problem in JSON Objects and Arrays with unicode characters. I put them in the realm file with `createAllFromJson` method of Realm object :

```
RealmConfiguration RealmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name("info.realm")
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .build();

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmConfig);
try{
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.createAllFromJson(AccountRecordObject.class, accounts);
            realm.createAllFromJson(SanadRecordObject.class, sanads);
            realm.createObjectFromJson(ConfigRecordObject.class, config);
        }
    });
}finally {
    realm.close();
}
```

and reading from Realm object :

```
RealmConfiguration RealmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name("info.realm")
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .build();

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmConfig);
try{
    TextView txt = parentView.findViewById(R.id.fileSampleTxt);
    String S = realm.where(AccountRecordObject.class).equalTo("AccNo", 300015).findFirst().getAccName();
    txt.setText(S);
}finally {
    realm.close();
}
```

The problem is when I want to get a result from Realm file, unicode characters are shown as '?' :
[image]

**Edit** :

There is no problem in unicode characters when I use createObject method instead of createAllFromJson and passing a value from JSONArray :

```
AccountRecordObject obj = realm.createObject(AccountRecordObject.class);
obj.setAccNo(10000001);
try {
    obj.setAccName(accounts.getJSONObject(4).getString("AccName"));
}catch (JSONException E){
    E.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems there is a problem in createAllFromJson and createObjectFromJson methods with unicode characters

Answer (score 1):

Realm stores unicode just fine, so most likely it is the font used in Android Studio that does not support the glyphs actually in the file.

Comment: There is no problem when I use createObject method. I have edited question post